# Any tricks so clipboard history won't be erased with Windows reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clipboard

I am looking for a way like modifying registry so the clipboard history won't be deleted with reboot. I know pinning is a solution, but I want it to be automatic.

Also I am aware of 3rd party apps that can do this, but I am looking for a solution for built-in Windows 10 clipboard history.

Comment: The default windows clipboard does not support it, but the new implementation may. I personally use ClipX (3rd party tool) and it does remember the clipboard history up to x even after a reboot,which is the best you can get anyway.

Comment: I personally use [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10 1809 or later, and don't mind syncing your clipboard to the cloud, you can use the cloud clipboard feature.  An added benefit to this is you have access to the text you copy on your other devices as well.

Scroll to about a quarter of the page down in [this article](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/cloud-clipboard-windows-10) to get it setup

Comment: It would've been more useful if you've wrote the actual solution instead of giving a link which might be dead after a while, or the information in it changed. (I found it down myself at the time of this comment).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, Win+v brings up the new clipboard, and it does remember the history and doesn't clear it on reboot.
Of course, if Windows hadn't updated the clipboard, then you'd have to use third party software such as Ditto, because sitting around and wishing for a feature isn't really a strategy for success with Microsoft. ;)

Comment: Reboot deletes them!

Comment: Interesting. With me it doesn't. So there must be some setting somewhere.

Comment: Probably you are using hybernation or fastboot, or anything else that does not properly shut down the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Try ditto

https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/

That persists after reboot. And it's searchable.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150881)